# Contact form 500 Error - PHP

Tags: php, html, contact-form

I have tried looking around for a solution but I have yet to find one! It is probably a simple error but I cannot work it out.
I simply cannot get the online contact form working - it displays a 500 error page.

The PHP:

```
<?php
$myemail = "me@myemail.com";
$name = $_POST['name'];
$phone = $_POST['phone']
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$message = "
*MESSAGE FROM ONLINE FORM* 
$message
Sent from:
Name: $name
E-mail: $email
Phone: $phone
";
mail($myemail, $name, $phone, $email, $message);
header('Location: http://thewebaddress.co.uk');
?>
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="contactform">
<form action="sendform.php" method="post">
Name:<br>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name"/ ><br>
Email:<br>
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" /><br/>
Phone:<br/>
<input type="text" name="phone" id="phone"  /><br/>
Message:<br/>
<textarea name="message" id="message" ></textarea>          
<input type="submit" value="Send Message!" class="button" id="submit" name="submitform" />
</form>    
    </div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are missing a semicolon `;` on line 4

Comment: ***Always*** look in the server error logs when you get a generic error like this as those logs will almost always contain information about the exact error.

Comment: As @GentlemanMax said you should have `$phone = $_POST['phone'];` at line 4. To catch such errors turn on error logging and check the logs.

Comment: PHP `mail()` uses 4 parameters also, not 5. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php - There is a 5th, but yours doesn't do as it should.

Answer (score 0):

You should check whether $_POST values are set and whether your mail call is correct. According to documentation it should be: mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] ).